# Data.table join between row values and column names

Tags: r, merge, data.table, tidyr

I have two data.tables as follows:

```
DT_1 <- data.table(Type = c("A1","B1","A1","B1"))
DT_2 <- data.table(A1 = c(1,2,3),A1_ref = c(4,5,6),
                   B1 = c(11,12,13,14),B1_ref = c(15,16,17,18))
```

Where I have "A1" as a 'Type' in DT_1, I want to bring across (as a single nested data table) DT_2 columns which start with 'A1' i.e. 'A1' and 'A1_ref'.

Similarly, where I have "B1" as a 'Type' in DT_1, I want to bring across the corresponding columns which start with 'B1' i.e. 'B1' and 'B1_ref'.

The intended output would be the following structure, where I have the data tables from DT_2 nested within a new column called "Ref_table" within DT_1:

```
  DT_1 <- data.table(Type = c("A1","B1","A1","B1"),
                     Ref_table = c(DT_3,DT_4,DT_3,DT_4))
```

Where:

```
  DT_3 <- data.table(A1 = c(1,2,3),A1_ref = c(4,5,6)) # and
  DT_4 <- data.table(B1 = c(1,2,3),B1_ref = c(4,5,6))
```

So far, I tried to melt / 'gather' (from Tidyr) DT_2 into a long format and then conduct an 'on' join with DT_1, but that didn't give me what I was after unfortunately.
I'm currently stumped as to what other approaches I could take.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Phil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you can use a named list to create the column `Ref_table`, e.g.,

```
DT_1[, Ref_table := split.default(DT_2, sub("_.*", "", names(DT_2)))[Type]]
```

and you will obtain

```
> DT_1
   Type         Ref_table
1:   A1 <data.table[3x2]>
2:   B1 <data.table[3x2]>
3:   A1 <data.table[3x2]>
4:   B1 <data.table[3x2]>

> DT_1[, Ref_table]
[[1]]
   A1 A1_ref
1:  1      4
2:  2      5
3:  3      6

[[2]]
   B1 B1_ref
1: 11     14
2: 12     15
3: 13     16

[[3]]
   A1 A1_ref
1:  1      4
2:  2      5
3:  3      6

[[4]]
   B1 B1_ref
1: 11     14
2: 12     15
3: 13     16
```

## Data

```
DT_1 <- data.table(Type = c("A1", "B1", "A1", "B1"))
DT_2 <- data.table(
  A1 = c(1, 2, 3), A1_ref = c(4, 5, 6),
  B1 = c(11, 12, 13), B1_ref = c(14, 15, 16)
)
```